# Python 2.7.7/Pygame - Stuck on Scrolling Random Images (pipes in flappy bird)

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently trying to make a pygame version of flappy bird (way more complicated than I thought) and am stuck on making the pipes generate at random heights. Could anyone help me with this? To make this same animated I want to generate the pipes a little past the right of the screen and delete them a little past the left. When I run the current code the pipe images are on top of each other in the top left corner and don't move. (The bird works though)

```
import pygame, random, sys

pygame.init()
icon = pygame.image.load('flappybirdicon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([284, 512])
pygame.display.set_caption("Flappy Bird")
bg = pygame.image.load('flappybirdbackground.png')
bgrect = bg.get_rect()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pipex = 335

class Bird(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos = [x, y]

class Pipe(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.height = height
        self.pos = [pipex, height]

    def scroll(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-3, 0)
        self.pos[0] -= 3
        self.rect.center = self.pos

def draw_pipes():
    pipe1_height = random.randint(115, screen.get_height())
    pipe1 = Pipe('flappybirdpipe.png', pipe1_height)
    pipe2_height = 397 - pipe1_height
    pipe2 = Pipe('flappybirdpipe2.png', pipe2_height)
    screen.blit(pipe1.image, pipe1.rect)
    screen.blit(pipe2.image, pipe2.rect)

bird = Bird('flappybirdbird.png', 142, 256)
draw_pipes()

while True:
    clock.tick(30)
    bird.pos[1] += 5
    bird.rect.center = bird.pos
    screen.blit(bg, bgrect)
    pipe1.scroll()
    pipe2.scroll()
    screen.blit(bird.image, bird.rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bird.pos[1] -= 75
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bird.pos[1] -= 75
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PyGame, but it looks like you're not setting an X coordinate for your pipes anywhere.  You're setting a height, but never a location.

It also looks like you're not saving the pipe data anywhere, so I imagine your code is also causing new pipes to be created/drawn every time draw_pipes() is called, which looks to be every frame.

Comment: Yes I am quite confused as to where to go with this and what to do, mainly with how to keep track of the pipe instances.